# GooglePlaces API is making my app file size huge. Is there anything I can do about this?

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, cocoapods, google-places-api

I am trying to use GooglePlacesAutocomplete in my app. I install via CocoaPods and my app's universal compressed and install sizes go from:

46.1 MB and 70.8 MB

to:

111 MB  and 356 MB

just by installing this CocoaPod. Is this normal? The CocoaPod 'GooglePlaces' is what I am installing and in doing so it also seems to install the 'GoogleMaps' pod. Anything I can do about this? Thanks!

Comment: turns out this was unrelated to GooglePlaces and had to do with other files in the app

Answer (score 0):

For sorry yes it's usual when you put 'googlePlaces' it's by default grabs with it 'googleMaps' and if you check the size of it inside the Pods folder it's nearly 132 MB plus other things like 'toolBox' and 'sessionFetcher' , I encountered it while doing a  [Demo](https://github.com/ShKhan9/MyAddresses)

Comment: Were you able to do anything to reduce the file size or no?

Comment: There examples inside that pod you can delete , but their size is in Kilo , you can't delete maps or the places because they depend on each others in compiling